# TJvWizard how to change page to specific TJvWizardInteriorPage?

Tags: delphi, vcl, jvcl

is it possible to change to a specific interior page on the wizard?
lets say I'm on page 2 and I want to move to 5 directly without the user clicking next button 3 times.

thanks!

Comment: The TJvWizard comes with source code. A quick scan of it (in about 60 seconds) shows that TJVWizard has a public property named `ActivePageIndex`.

Comment: thanks, I also managed to get what I needed by doing this: `JvWizard.ActivePage:= JvWizardInteriorPage5;`